Is Redis 5.1 supported by Tridion Web 8.5
Currently we are using Tridion web 8.5 version with redis on content delivery for caching purpose (we don’t know its version but probably it came bundled with 8.5).
Now we are asked to upgrade redis to version 5.1 and we couldn’t find any documentation whether web 8.5 would support it or not. Could anyone help us with any info about Redis 5.1 would be supported by Tridion web 8.5.

Note that SDL Web 8.5 isn't supported anymore at all by RWS.
